# How to switch GPUs without using the tray app of Power Manager (Lenovo T500)

Tags: gpu, vga, thinkpad, switch

So.. the laptop got two GPUs. Intel and ATI.
I can switch by opening the tray app, and choosing the VGA.

However, it's got a "non-standard" size, it makes my tray look weird.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Is it possible to switch the GPUs WITHOUT using the tray app?
Like a command line switch (bat file?) or something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [ColonelONeill](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/59141)'s answer taken from [here](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/T500-Is-it-possible-to-switch-GPUs-withoout-the-PowerMgr-tray/td-p/487489#M47348):

> For 32-bit Windows:
>
> "C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Utilities\PWMUIAux.exe" /HighPerformanceGpu
>   /ShowDialog
>   "C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Utilities\PWMUIAux.exe"
>   /EnergySavingGpu /ShowDialog
>
> For 64-bit Windows:
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\ThinkPad\Utilities\PWMUIAux.exe"
>   /HighPerformanceGpu /ShowDialog "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ThinkPad\Utilities\PWMUIAux.exe" /EnergySavingGpu /ShowDialog
>
> You still need Power Manager installed, as well as the switchable
>   graphics driver package provided by Lenovo (not AMD/ATI or Intel).